# How to create a complex transfer function amplifier bjt based

Tags: amplifier, bjt, transfer-function

I need to create an amplifier as shown in the first photo bellow, where we have a 20dB/dec rise  and at the end of transfer function -40db/dec decline.
I see we have a zero and then a double pole.
A basic bjt amplifier was created with 2n2222 in PSPICE shown bellow,Its transfer function in the last photo is far from the transfer function i need.
I can add another stages and mosfets or feedback to my bjt frst  stage.
could you recommend a structure which structure has a similar transfer pole zero transfer function structure as shown in the first photo bellow?

Thanks.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have a very wide bandwidth and you will need more stages. \$\sqrt{170\:\text{Hz}\cdot 170\:\text{MHz}}=170\:\text{kHz}\$. That's the center frequency. The fractional bandwidth is \$\frac{f_{_\text{H}}\:-\: f_{_\text{L}}}{f_{_\text{0}}}=\frac{170\:\text{MHz}\:-\: 170\:\text{Hz}}{170\:\text{kHz}}\approx 1000\$. So definitely a low-pass and a high-pass.

Comment: Hello Jonk,How can i see what is the bandwidth improvement regarding adding a stage?  What about the double pole in the end ,How can i achieve it?
Is there a structure in LTSPICE you can recommend which i could start build and analise to get such response? Thanks.

Comment: Given the flatness and the incredible bandwidth involved I think this is a Butterworth and also I do NOT know which BJTs to attempt here. This is crazy on the high-end. Are you absolutely sure about that upper limit?

Comment: Hello jonk,my base stage is 2n2222,suppose i want to add another stage,even mosfet based,how can i make the double polein the end?(assuming we cannot reach such high bandwidth)

Comment: It's a first order on the low end and a 2nd order on the high end. But the upper frequency is beyond my knowledge. I've never attempted anything that high with discrete construction. But I'm just a hobbyist. Maybe some expert here can tell you how. Your fractional bw is insane. Never encountered a problem that wide. You'll need to find more reasonable numbers if I'm to be of any good. I did write something [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/475139/38098) that may help a little, though.

Comment: Hello jonk,Assuming the high frequency is wrong.
COuld you show me a method of creating first order at the start and second order in the end with bjt and mosfet cascode?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't know why you want a cascode (bjt or fet) layout. Is there some reason that particular topology is required? Also, one BJT can yield 2nd order but in general that's without any voltage gain (actually slightly less than 1.) Your diagram doesn't indicate the required voltage gain and that's another issue. And there are other complications that would make this a long, dragged out discussion if it were to be of help. If not, there's little point starting. We can't write textbooks here. Read the link I gave. (And it's possible to replace opamps with BJT stages.)

Comment: Hello jonk,How do i create a second order pole?

Comment: Two capacitors come to mind. But it really sounds to me, now, that you've very very little clues, yet. You aren't prepared to design things because it appears to me now that you don't even understand the concepts that are brought into play in order to design them. That means you need to set this aside for a bit and work first on building up some skill regarding the foundations you'll need to apply here.

Comment: I cannot be your personal interactive encyclopedia. I have a life, too. One day, perhaps, artificial intelligence and computer technologies may be able to marshal human knowledge into such an interactive encyclopedia. But we aren't quite there, yet. So there may be a little wait. In the meantime, we have to earn our knowledge the old fashion way -- by working hard for it.